# How to generate a PDF/A with TexStudio?

Tags: pdf-a

I need to generate a PDF/A format with TexStudio, is it possible ? Should I use other ide to do that ?

Comment: The  editor is irrelevant. Check the pdfx package: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfx